Looking for suggestions for alternate notation of linear functions from a group to a field
I am looking for an alternate notation to $\mathrm{Hom}(G,\mathbb C)$ for the vector space linear functionals from a free Abelian group $G$ to the complex numbers (or any field). The only problem I have with the notation is that it is cumbersome, and I would like something that is cleaner to put in something like a category theory diagram. Also, what can the vector space be referred to as besides "The space of $\mathbb C$-linear functionals on $G$"? Something along the lines of "The dual space of $G$".
I would like to use $G^*$ like the dual of a vector space, but this would be incorrect because the actual dual of the group is $G^* = Hom(G,\mathbb Z)$. I also like the set theory notation $\mathbb C^G$ but this doesn't connote the linearity of the functions.
Thank you.

I've sometimes seen $X'$ to denote the algebraic dual of a vector space X, i.e. the set of all linear forms to the underlying field.

@lphil Oh interesting, in that case I shouldn't have a problem defining $G^* = \mathrm{Hom}(G,\mathbb C)$ since I can reserve $G'$ for the actual dual $\mathrm{Hom}(G,\mathbb Z)$. Thanks

Sure. Just be sure to state your definitions at the start of your work and nobody will be confused, as especially $X'$ and $X^*$ can mean wildly different things, at least in functional analysis, where the former is $\mathrm{Hom}(X,\mathbb{F})$ and the latter $\mathrm{Hom}(X,\mathbb{F})\cap C(X,\mathbb{F})$ given $\mathbb F = \mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.
